# Multiples router url

Tags: angular, authentication, ionic-framework, angular-routing, router

**How to hide multiple url router like this?**
I want to hide the header in various views / pages

```
  <ion-header *ngIf="!isHeader()">

  isHeader() {
    return this.router.url === '/view';
  }
```

Comment: You can use this.router.navigate(['view']) based on the condition of click element

Comment: Tip: Avoid using function calling `isHeader()` from the template, it triggers every time change detection runs in the background.

Answer (score 0):

To check the url you can use lodash .includes

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';
const url = this.router.url.split(/[?#]/)[0];
return _.includes(url, 'view');
```

This will also be true for all pages where the url is view/... so you might need to extend this check.